# Keeping DLL versions up to date

Tags: c#, deployment

I have a fairly straightforward multi layer c# application, with different presentation tiers in ASP.net MVC (2 different websites and a separate API) as well as a desktop application.  The desktop application is installed on 20 end user machines.

The data (EF), entities and service layers are shared by all of the presentation tiers as there is a large amount of crossover and in most cases it is either just the view or authentication logic that changes.  My question is around best practice approaches to keeping those DLLs in sync.  When updating the code for a mchange to one of the UIs should it trigger a deploy of all of them to ensure consistency?  If so, what automation tools are available (mainly thinking about the websites which are hosted on Azure, the desktop app is always deployed manually)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It's a code change; you treat it like you would any other code change.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear.  I appreciate it is a code change however that code change then compiles to a library (say services.dll) which exists in several separate live systems.  I was looking for strategies to simplify keeping these in sync and to avoid having different versions across these systems.  Currently this is managed manually, with all systems being redeployed however it feels cumbersome.  One approach I have considered is a central codebase with REST API however I'm not sure that the added HTTP overhead is worthwhile

Comment: Well, a REST API is pretty much a rewrite, but you're right; it would solve the repository DLL problem.  I assume your 20 machines are on a local area network, correct?  The advantages to moving everything to a REST API should be obvious, but it would be a lot of work just to cater to 20 local machines.  Have you considered a [ClickOnce installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

My first reflex here would be to treat each applications as an atomic entity.  If the shared parts are very large (which seems to be the case here) I would coordinate deployment between all and update them all together.  This approach works well with ClickOnce for example.

You could also go the continuous update route but that tends to be less stable as you will deploy less tested components.  If you choose continuous deployment you will need solid versioning scheme and conventions and they will need to be followed fiercely.  There will be times where the changes in the DLL will induce breaking changes in other components present so again coordinating and packaging releases will allow to insert additional testing prior to releasing.  The most important part of a continuous deployment scheme is by far the ability to quickly rollback a version should it go south so you must ensure that either you coordinate the rollback on all tier simultaneously or ensure a solid enough architecture to allow the shared tiers (Servers) to serve clients of various versions.

So, in brief, the easiest option is to bundle a bunch of changes together and package each application in order to roll them out simultaneously.  Added advantage is that the versioning can be unified if that's something your team feels important.

Anything else I see as basically an optimisation of this baseline situation.